# The block is not deleted after saving ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am writing my plugin, and there was a problem when saving, the block is added and deleted when inserting, but if you save it, it is not deleted.

It seems to me that the block after saving is not detected by ckeditor 5, so it is not active for deletion, but I do not understand what this is related to

The whole code:

```
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';
import { toWidget, toWidgetEditable } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/src/utils';
import Widget from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/src/widget';

class GalleryImport extends Plugin {
     static get requires() {          
        return [ Widget ];
    }
    
     init() {
        const editor = this.editor;
         
        this._defineSchema();  
        this._defineConverters();

        editor.ui.componentFactory.add( 'galleryimport', () => {
            // The button will be an instance of ButtonView.
            const button = new ButtonView();

            button.set( {
                label: 'Insert gallery',
                icon: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M13.75 9v2.25H16v1.5h-2.25V15h-1.5v-2.25H10v-1.5h2.25V9h1.5ZM0 9.661l7.005 2.71L9 11.598v1.687l-1.71.662a.791.791 0 0 1-.456.033l-.111-.033L0 11.348V9.662Zm0-3.48L7.005 8.89 14 6.186v1.687l-6.71 2.595a.781.781 0 0 1-.456.034l-.111-.034L0 7.869V6.181ZM7.135.015l.083.026L14 2.77v1.689L7.29 7.053a.791.791 0 0 1-.456.034l-.111-.034L0 4.455V2.767l.011.003L6.794.04a.566.566 0 0 1 .34-.026Zm-.13 1.257L1.717 3.431l5.288 2.044 5.312-2.055-5.312-2.148Z"/></svg>',
                tooltip: true
            } );
            
             button.on( 'execute', () => {
                editor.model.change( writer => {
                    editor.model.insertObject( creategalleryImport( writer, 'Gallery 2' , '151', 'background-image: url(https://catherineasquithgallery.com/uploads/posts/2021-02/1614385475_77-p-svetlo-zelenii-fon-abstraktsiya-80.jpg)') );
                } );
            } );

            return button;
        } );
        
      
    }
    
    _defineSchema() {                                                          
        const schema = this.editor.model.schema;

        schema.register( 'galleryImport', {
             inheritAllFrom: '$blockObject',
             allowContentOf: '$block',
             allowAttributes: [ 'id', 'title', 'style', 'class' ]
        } );
        
    }

    
   _defineConverters() {                                                      
        const conversion = this.editor.conversion;

        conversion.for( 'upcast' ).elementToElement( {
            view: {
                name: 'section',
                classes: 'gallery-box',
                attributes: [ 'id', 'title', 'style', 'class' ]
            },
            model: ( viewElement, { writer: viewWriter } ) => {
            
          const section = viewWriter.createElement( 'galleryImport', { id: viewElement.getAttribute( 'id' ), title: viewElement.getAttribute( 'title' ), style: viewElement.getAttribute( 'style' ),  class: 'gallery-box' } );
         
         return toWidget( section, viewWriter, { label: 'gallery box widget' } );
           
        }
        } );
        
        
        conversion.for( 'downcast' ).elementToElement( {
             model: {
            name: 'galleryImport',
            classes: 'gallery-box',
            attributes: [ 'id', 'title', 'style', 'class' ]
        },
            view: ( modelElement, { writer: viewWriter } ) => {
                const section = viewWriter.createContainerElement('section', { id: modelElement.getAttribute( 'id' ), title: modelElement.getAttribute( 'title' ), style: modelElement.getAttribute( 'style' ),  class: 'gallery-box' } );
                return toWidget( section, viewWriter, { label: 'simple box widget' } );
            }
        } );
        
    }
}



function creategalleryImport( writer , name, galleryid, imageUrl) {
    const galleryImport = writer.createElement( 'galleryImport', {id: galleryid, title: name, style: imageUrl});
    return galleryImport;
}
```

[image]

data that saves:

[image]

how to make it deleted and when saving?
there is probably an error in the code